# Swiper Slider navigation arrows - texting cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I have problem which is frustrating me.
I have set up Swiper slider on my html - works fine no prob, but problem is with arrows -
i dont know why but when arrow is clicked then texting cursor appears and i think it shouldnt be that way.
Does someone has faced similar problem and how solved it?
thanks

Image 
[image]

css for buttons -
`.main-slider .swiper-button-prev {

```
position: absolute;

background-repeat: no-repeat;

height: 50px;
width: 50px;
border-radius: 50%;
top: 30px;
```

}

.main-slider .swiper-button-next {

```
position: absolute;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: #40A2D5;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
border-radius: 50%;
top: 30px;
```

}`

`.arrow-container {

```
min-height: 66px;
max-width: 120px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
border-radius: 65px;
position: relative;
margin-top: 80px;
margin-bottom: 65px;
```

}`

and the same problem is with HTML forms -
I can click outside form and this frustrating text enter cursor appears - probably it shows div but is it suppose to do that?
Image 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQ3Lx.png)

Comment: what are you trying to make? please ask questions with your codes. We can't pretend what are you trying to do

Comment: @debugger i could paste code but thats maybt not code problem - i have done what i wanted but the problem is that when i click on arrows this text enter appear each time. Arrows are png images but this cursor shows that i could write something there!

Comment: @debugger same problem is with html forms with input i can click on form in html and text enter cursor shows up in the beginning - is this problem with css or html?

Comment: @debugger ive updated post

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I thought that it was because of the swiperjs, but actually, in my case, I have accidentally enabled caret browsing mode in Chrome by clicking F7 button. Click F7 again to disable that mode. That option can be managed in settings in Accessibility page.